# How synchronize Active Directory Info?

Tags: active-directory

Ok this maybe a dumb question. Let me explain the situation first. I work for Org A. we host a suite of intranet web applications, which are authenticated by active directory. We are currently migrating the applications to Org B.

Assume everything else work as expected.

How do we share user authentication information from Org A to Org B? At the end of migration, Org A still has its own AD, but we want changes to this AD to be reflected on Org B's AD (with small delay of several hours or a day). For the initiate test site on Org B, their AD is synchronized by a manual export/import process. It is unrealistic to perform this process daily or hourly.

Comment: adfs or something similar would be a better solution. No export required and very little delay when users change passwords etc

Comment: Why not create a domain trust relationship between the two organizations? Send to me that could work too, beside adfs as @Drifter104 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to establish a one way domain trust relationship.  Here is a good over view. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178%28WS.10%29.aspx